# About creating domain extension like .com

Tags: dns, hosting

I want to create my own domain extension (for example `.com`); we want to create `.clickit`. What is the procedure for that?

Comment: That's a [top level domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), you can't (yet!) just make them up yourself.

Comment: https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

ICANN is the organisation that  is responsible for this. Visit their website for information on beginning the process. Their website for new gTLDs is https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/.